# How to do a MYSQL INNER JOIN on two Python lists with the same elements?

Tags: python, mysql, list, inner-join

I have two python3 arrays(lists) similar to two columns in MYSQL. Some of their first 'column' elements are the same:

```
list1 = [ 

['a', 'apple'], 
['b', 'banana'], 
['m', 'mango']

]

list2 = [ 

['b', 'buffalo'], 
['zzzz', 'zzzzegemot, a sleeping behemoth'], 
['m', 'mongoose']

]
```

Notice that in both lists the first 'b' and the third 'm' elements are the same.

How can I do something similar to MYSQL INNER JOIN on list1[0] and list2[0] and get a third that is the combination of similar entries in columns:

```
list3 = [

['banana', 'buffalo']
['mango', 'mongoose']

]
```

I hope I expressed myself clearly for you to understand me.

Comment: MySQL does not exclusively own `INNER JOIN`. You most likely meant an SQL `INNER JOIN`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have two lists, the inner join should take care of repeating keys.

```
m1 = reduce(lambda c,x: c[x[0]].append(x[1]) or c,list1,defaultdict(list))
list(chain(*(product(m1[e[0]],[e[1]]) for e in list2)))

# added entries ['b', 'bongo']  and ['b', 'bull'] into list1 and list2
>>> [('banana', 'buffalo'),
     ('bongo', 'buffalo'),
     ('banana', 'bull'),
     ('bongo', 'bull'),
     ('mango', 'mongoose')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting `list1`, `list2` to dictionaries make it easy to do what you want:

```
>>> list1 = [
...     ['a', 'apple'],
...     ['b', 'banana'],
...     ['m', 'mango']
... ]
>>>
>>> list2 = [
...     ['b', 'buffalo'],
...     ['zzzz', 'zzzzegemot, a sleeping behemoth'],
...     ['m', 'mongoose']
... ]
>>>
>>> d1, d2 = dict(list1), dict(list2)
>>> common_keys = set(d1) & set(d2)  # => {'b', 'm'}  keys that appears in both dicts.
>>> [[d1[k], d2[k]] for k in common_keys]
[['banana', 'buffalo'], ['mango', 'mongoose']]
```